# Fix IP adress cannot is not taken from YAML container deployement

Tags: yaml, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have a YAM file which deploy a container into a subnet.
The idea to to be able to define a fix IP address for my containers when it start
For that I have define the IP entry as seen in following screen shot :

https://o365itecor-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/s_calderara_itecor_com/EfZyTI06hk9Kg1NnjEbARq0BDyv01xBo_R0ryLmxY-xgmA?e=zuPr8C

Normally, the IP should be set to 10.0.0.5 but Azure assign it all time to 10.0.0.4

Any idea why I cannot set fixed IP address ?

Regards

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code, post your code instead.

Comment: Can you try with IP value as "10.0.0.5" instead of 10.0.0.5

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT, what do you mean this is what I have done in my yaml code, the IP is set to 10.0.0.5 but when container gets deployed, it gets IP 10.0.0.4 ?

Comment: As per the screenshot, the value of IP is taken as int data type. We need to send it as string. Try to keep the value in double quotes and try once

Comment: I add the IP as string "10.0.0.5 "and the container did not get the adress gven in my yml file but instead it gets 10.0.0.4

Answer (score 0):

As of now, assigning a fixed private IP address to container instance is not supported.

Whenever we create a container instance with a virtual network, the first private IP address available in the subnet will be assigned to the container instance.

In your case, as the first available private IP address available in the subnet is 10.0.0.4, the container is created with this IP address.